# jslint named parameter error

Tags: jquery, jslint

My code

```
str = str.replace(/@@(.+)@@/g, function () {
    return myObj[arguments[1]];
});
```

Why does jslint gives an error "Use a named parameter" at line 2?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jslint is advising you against using the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) pseudo-array, because of performance concerns in some browsers.

You can specify named parameters in your function instead, and use these:

```
str = str.replace(/@@(.+)@@/g, function(match, submatch) {
    return myObj[submatch];
});
```